# wsd2java failure with axis2 1.6.2

Tags: variables, duplicates, axis, declaration, wsdl2java

I am getting following error when trying for wsdl2java

:\axis2-1.6.2\bin>wsdl2java -uri X.wsdl 
sing AXIS2_HOME:   C:\axis2-1.6.2 
sing JAVA_HOME:    C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\java 
etrieving document at 'X.wsdl'. 
og4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger  
(org.apache.axis2.description.WSDL11ToAllAxisServicesBuilder). 
og4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly. 
Location of error unknown)Duplicate variable declaration for: 'basePropertyType' 
Location of error unknown)Duplicate variable declaration for: 'propertyName' 
Location of error unknown)Duplicate variable declaration for: 'propertyType' 
Location of error unknown)Duplicate variable declaration for: 'shortTypeNameUncapped' 
Location of error unknown)Duplicate variable declaration for: 'shortTypeName' 
Location of error unknown)Duplicate variable declaration for: 'javaName' 
Location of error unknown)Duplicate variable declaration for: 'basePropertyType' 
Location of error unknown)Duplicate variable declaration for: 'inputcount' 
Location of error unknown)Duplicate variable declaration for: 'inputcount' 
Location of error unknown)Duplicate variable declaration for: 'basePropertyType' 
Location of error unknown)Duplicate variable declaration for: 'propertyName' 
Location of error unknown)Duplicate variable declaration for: 'propertyType' 
Location of error unknown)Duplicate variable declaration for: 'shortTypeNameUncapped' 
Location of error unknown)Duplicate variable declaration for: 'shortTypeName' 
Location of error unknown)Duplicate variable declaration for: 'javaName' 
Location of error unknown)Duplicate variable declaration for: 'basePropertyType' 
:\axis2-1.6.2\bin>wsdl2java -uri C:\axis2-1.6.2\bin\X.wsdl

Any idea ?

I think this was because of the JDK used. I used Oracle JDK. 1.7, then it resolved the issue. 
Please use Oracle JDK instead of IBM. But if you are forced to use IBM JDK then I dont think there is any option.